# Domain name in Node.JS

Tags: linux, node.js

I have a VPS on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/).

I have a **Node.JS** and **MongoDB** application.
Now I want to pin my domain (myapp.com) to my Node.JS app.

Now I can run my app by IP like 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080. I want to have this on address myapp.com.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A domain does not point to an app but to a machine, so to start make sure your domain points to your VPS's IP, i guess you can access to DNS settings in your host's interface.

If your app is running on :8080 then http://myapp.com:8080 should then point to your app.

If you want your app to run on the http://myapp.com only (without :8080) you have to either launch the app on port 80 (which is the default http port) or install a reverse proxy that tunnels :80 to :8080.

I personally recommend using a proxy, as you would be able to add other NodeJs apps later, each running on different ports and beeing served through the proxy.

Nginx is used a lot as a reverse proxy for node or ruby applications, and you should find a lot of documentation for it.

Alternatively, to play pure NodeJS, have a look at [node-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy), it should suit your needs very well too.

Comment: There is a good article on DigitalOcean on how to configure Nginx to do this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab